# Numba doesn't work for numpy.random function

Tags: python, numpy, numba, jit

I am trying to implement Numba on a simple Monte Carlo integrator.

```
import numpy as np
import numba
import time

@numba.njit
def integrator(integrand,
               lower_bounds,
               upper_bounds,
               n):

    if len(lower_bounds) != len(upper_bounds):
        raise ValueError("Lower and upper bounds are of different dimensions.")

    x = np.random.uniform(lower_bounds,
                          upper_bounds,
                          (n, len(lower_bounds)))

    summation = 0
    for i in x:
        summation += integrand(i)
    domain = np.prod(np.subtract(upper_bounds, lower_bounds))

    integral = domain/n*summation

    return integral


start = time.time()
integrator(numba.njit(lambda x: x**2),
           np.array([-5]),
           np.array([5]),
           10000000)
end = time.time()

print(end-start)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
>>> integrator(numba.njit(lambda x: x**2),
...            np.array([-5]),
...            np.array([5]),
...            10000000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
←[1m←[1m←[1mNo implementation of function Function(<built-in method uniform of numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState object at 0x0000019A9E477040>) found for signature:
 
 >>> uniform(array(int32, 1d, C), array(int32, 1d, C), UniTuple(int64 x 2))
 
There are 4 candidate implementations:
←[1m      - Of which 4 did not match due to:
      Overload in function '_OverloadWrapper._build.<locals>.ol_generated': File: numba\core\overload_glue.py: Line 129.
        With argument(s): '(array(int32, 1d, C), array(int32, 1d, C), UniTuple(int64 x 2))':←[0m
←[1m       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypingError: ←[1mNo match←[0m←[0m
  raised from C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\overload_glue.py:162
←[0m
←[0m←[1mDuring: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in method uniform of numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState object at 0x0000019A9E477040>)←[0m
←[0m←[1mDuring: typing of call at <stdin> (21)
←[0m
←[1m
File "<stdin>", line 21:←[0m
←[1m<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>←[0m
```

It seems that there is some issue with passing dimensions as a tuple argument to `np.random.uniform()`. However, I know that `np.random.uniform()` is supported by Numba and using tuples there is necessary. What is the problem here?

Comment: I suspect the low/high values should a scalar, not an array. Is it really necessary like this, since you immediately loop over the output?

Comment: @RutgerKassies low/high values are arrays, to allow for integration of n-dimensional functions (a pair of bounds for each dimension). What does the fact that I'm looping over `x` immediately have to do with anything?

Comment: In the end `np.random.uniform` has indeed an array in parameter (which is not supported by the function). This is not clear what you want but a scalar in indeed required so maybe you need `np.random.uniform(lower_bounds[0],upper_bounds[0], ...)` or maybe a loop should be added.

Comment: The support in `numba` seems to be limited to scalar bounds. You could use `rnd = np.random.rand(n, len(lower_bounds)); x = (upper_bounds - lower_bounds) * rnd + lower_bounds` as a work around.

Comment: The `numpy` list for distribution functions has this clear note: `The size argument is not supported in the following functions.`  You have provided a size tuple.  Using arrays for the bounds is a "sneaky" of providing a size to the numpy version.

Comment: @hpaulj - I can't find this note in the latest [release's documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html#supported-numpy-features). Providing the `size` argument works for `np.random.uniform` with scalar bounds.